# Gedit Snippets Plugin : How do you use the "tab trigger"?

Tags: linux, centos, gedit

I enabled "snippets" in gedit.
i added a new snippet.

```
Value: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Tab Trigger : a

Shortcut key : CTRL + 1

Drop targets : none
```

everytime i press CTRL + 1

it inserts

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

which is fine, but what is this

Tab Trigger about ?

How can i make use of it ?

is `a` suppose to get replaced with `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`
automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tab trigger setting is used for tab completion. When you'll press `a` and then TAB - you'll see `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`. Pretty useful, by the way.

Comment: i couldn't have figured this out without this answer

Comment: You have to be in the correct file type for this to work.  "bash"<tab> only works if the language is set to "sh".